# Unable to push Server Work Queue Length custom metric to Cloud Watch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I am unable to publish **Server Work Queue Length** custom metric to Cloud Watch. I was able to figure out my mistake but unable to do it as I am clueless as to what to use there.

This is the **PerformanceCounter** block for this metric :

```
{
    "Id": "PerformanceCounter",
    "FullName": "AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch.PerformanceCounterComponent.PerformanceCounterInputComponent,AWS.EC2.Windows.CloudWatch",
    "Parameters": {
         "CategoryName": "Server Work Queues",
         "CounterName": "Queue Length",
         "InstanceName": "",
         "MetricName": "QueueDepth",
         "Unit": "Count",
         "DimensionName": "InstanceId",
         "DimensionValue": "{instance_id}"
    }
},
```

The ***problem*** with the above code is the ***InstanceName*** parameter.

According to **AWS Documentation**,

In the InstanceName parameter, enter valutes from the Add Counters
   dialog box in Performance Monitor, which can be one of the following:

- Blank, if the selected object has no instances.
- A single instance of the selected object.
- _Total to use the aggregate of all instances.

**Note:** Do not use an asterisk (*) to indicate all instances because each performance    counter component only supports one metric.

Add Counters dialog box in Performance Monitor shows the following :

[image]

So the Counters Section shows **All instances**. AWS Documentation, as bulleted above says not to use * if the counter shows All Instances, but doesnot say what to use. I have used _Total and also left it blank. Both of them did not work.

By following the same points mentioned above, I successfully monitored Memory, Logical Disk Space, Paging File etc.

For Paging File, I used **_Total** as the InstanceName as it is mentioned there in the Performance Counter. Below snapshot shows that.

[image]

For Logical Disk Free Space, I used the **_Total** as InstanceName as the counter in the PerformanceMonitor showed up.

[image]

For Memory, I left the InstanceName value as **blank** as the counter in the PerformanceMonitor showed nothing.

[image]

I have been trying this from almost three days without any success. Please suggest me what to use there.

Comment: Where is the documentation for this metric? Where did you get it from?

Comment: We need to get it from Performance Monitor. It is available in every Windows Server. All custom metrics are pulled from there only. Search your server for performance monitor. Counter Name, Category Name.....all these parameters are pulled from there. I have edited my question. You would understand it better now. Please check

Answer (score 0):

According to the documantation:

> For each performance counter that you want to upload to CloudWatch, copy the PerformanceCounter section and change the Id parameter to make it unique (e.g., "PerformanceCounter2") and update the other parameters as necessary.

Assuming that you have other `PerformanceCounter` sections in your `JSON` file, you should have unique ids for each section. Everything else seems fine.

Comment: I have only one Performance Counter and that is Serve Work Queue Length

Comment: Could you post the entire `JSON` file?

Comment: I have figured out the issue but unable to solve it as I do not know what to use. I have updated my question along with snapshots. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try high level API call like this:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-cloudwatch-publish-custom-metrics.html

I followed this and found no issue.